# Laravel - Looping through a nested collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreach, laravel-blade

**Function to get all the required data:**

```
$auditResults = Audit::where('audit_id', $id)
    ->with('questionDetail')
    ->with('questionDetail.auditQuestion')
    ->get();
```

Which returns (streamlined):

```
Audit {#427 ▼
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "questionDetail" => AuditQuestionDetail {#449 ▼
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "auditQuestion" => AuditQuestion {#471 ▼
          #original: array:5 [▶]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I loop within the view, to reach the `auditQuestion` relationship, for each `Audit`?

I have tried:

```
@foreach($auditResults->questionDetail->auditQuestion as $answer)
```

But I get:

> Undefined property:
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$questionDetail

Many thanks.

** Issue with first relationship: **

```
   Collection {#470 ▼
  #items: array:18 [▼
    0 => Audit {#427 ▼
      #fillable: array:4 [▶]
      #attributes: array:7 [▶]
      #original: array:7 [▶]
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "questionDetail" => AuditQuestionDetail {#449 ▼
          #table: "audit_questions_details"
          #fillable: array:3 [▶]
          #attributes: array:7 [▶]
          #original: array:7 [▼
            "id" => 2
            "audit_question_id" => 2
            "question_number" => 1
            "comment" => 1
            "header" => 0
            "created_at" => "2017-03-26 13:40:18"
            "updated_at" => "2017-03-26 13:40:18"
          ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 5.4, you can use [higher order messages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#higher-order-messages) to do this cleanly:

```
@foreach($auditResults->map->questionDetail->map->auditQuestion as $answer)
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, this returns `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$map`

Comment: I would consider updating your Laravel version if possible. Otherwise, you can use the answer from @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: Removed comment.

Comment: Many thanks, unfortunately it returns `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$questionDetail`. I'm unsure why I'm having trouble with the first relationship.

Comment: I have updated the description with a more detailed view of the first relationship.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure. I get the `Undefined property` error if I run it in Laravel 5.3 but it works in 5.4 for me. Maybe check `composer.json` and run `composer update` and `composer dumpautoload` just to be sure?

Comment: You were right, I was using 5.2! The problem of working on multiple projects. I upgraded to 5.4, and your command works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome, glad we stuck with it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use nested loops:

```
@foreach ($auditResults as $result)
    @foreach ($result->questionDetail as $detail)
        @foreach ($detail->auditQuestion as $question)
            {{ $question->id }}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you, but using the above returns `Undefined variable: questionDetail`. Also, is there a reason why `questionDetail` has a $ preceding it, but not `auditQuestion` on the line below?

Comment: @Ben there was a typo, just remove the `$` sign before the `questionDetail`

Comment: Thank you. It now returns this error `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: @Ben I don't see the data so I can't give you an exact code to solve the error. Just add the check like `@if (!is_null($question))` for empty objects and relatioships

Comment: If I only use the `foreach` for this `@foreach ($result->questionDetail as $detail) {{ $detail }} @endforeach`, it returns `1`. I would have expected this to return the data from the relationship. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @Ben yes, it should be a collection

Comment: This is what I ended up doing however would someone has a more abstract / reccursive way to achieve this - I need to loop through each relation of a collection, no matter what the models are